# TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY make keyboard can't appearing

Tags: android, kotlin, keyboard, floating, type-application-overlay

i got a struggle with my apps, i'm planned to add floating text in my apps im using this code:

```
  wmParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY
        else WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,

        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    )
```

this code running as i want, but then when i try to type something on another application, the keyboard wont show up. but the rest (e.g. button, gesture, opening other apps) was running, but not with the keyboard

i've already tried:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
```

but none of these works
any other ideas?
thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i've found the solution

need to implement multiple flag

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,
```

hopefully help someone

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have been searching for a day for the same issue, It helped me a lot.